# Run 2 sql query with 1 query for save query result as .csv format

Tags: php, mysql

In my web I've 2 page. **1) admin.php   2) csv.php.** In admin.php page following query is showing data from db. In csv.php page I used same query to save data to .csv format  but Can't save it.

I decided to run this same query in ONE QUERY. So that I can get the query result and can save it to csv format.

**Questions:**

1) How do i run this query to ONE query ?

2) Following query is showing data successfully. So how do i save it as .csv file ?

I search **google** for that and found many result which is showing how do I save data as .csv format with only one query. But you see that I've 2 while statement in my query then how do i save it  as .csv format ? NO idea  :(

Thanks and Looking for your help. :)
**Note:** I'm new learner about php and mysql.

```
$sqlagentdetails = "select * from users WHERE company_name != ''";
$rowresult = mysql_query($sqlagentdetails); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rowresult, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $pc1 = $row['pc1'];
    $pc2 = $row['pc2'];
    $pc3 = $row['pc3'];
    $pc4 = $row['pc4'];                      
    $emailAgent = $row['user_email'];                      
    $user_id = $row['id'];


$myQuery =  mysql_query("
 SELECT * 
   FROM user_property upr 
  WHERE (postcode = '$pc1' OR
         postcode = '$pc2' OR
         postcode = '$pc3' OR
         postcode = '$pc4') AND
         datediff(CURDATE(), upr.creation_date) <= 7 AND
         NOT EXISTS(SELECT ofr.property_id 
                      FROM offers ofr 
                     WHERE ofr.property_id = upr.property_id AND
                           ofr.agent_id IN(SELECT id 
                                             FROM users 
                                            WHERE company_name !=''
                                          )
                   )
ORDER BY property_id DESC");


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($myQuery)){

    // more data are goes to here...     

    }
}
```

Comment: So, what exactly is you question? how to combine these two queries or how to create a csv file?

Comment: @EhsanT Thanks for your reply. Question is..How to create a csv file from this query.

Comment: I can see that you already are using some code like the one @Abhi Beckert have posted, but you say you can not achieve what you are trying for. so do you get any errors, or what happens? can you explain more please?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) How do i run this query to ONE query ?

You don't want it to run as one query. It's usually better to have lots of small simple queries instead of one complicated query. In fact I would suggest you update your code to have even more queries, for example the contents of the "not exists()" should not be done as a subquery, it should be a completely separate query to improve performance.

> 2) Following query is showing data successfully. So how do i save it as .csv file ?

There are two parts, first you need to send the correct HTTP headers to trigger a CSV download:

```
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv";' );
```

Then just print out the data in CSV format:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($myQuery)) {
  $first = true;
  foreach ($row as $cell) {
    if ($first)
      $first = false;
    else
      print ',';

    print '"' . addslashes($cell) . '"';
  }
  print "\n";
}
```

Note: CSV is a bad format, and this will only work in some editions of Microsoft Excel. Depending where the user lives (eg: Europe) it might not work properly. For most editions of Excel the above will work however. There is no good solution except to avoid using CSV.

Comment: It's not save the data as csv format. I just paste your code to `// more data are goes to here...`

Comment: @Babu you're going to need to figure out why it's not working for yourself. What I've posted is the correct approach, go through each line of code and find out why it's not working.