# can't save sql query output to .csv format

Tags: php, mysql

I'm facing a problem with sql query plz someone assist me.

In my admin panel there are few options to download data as. csv format which is come by using **sql query** from database. All query is **single query** and can download data as .csv format successfully  **except** following **Sql Query**. I can't download this query result as.csv format.

That's why I'm asking this question that how do i save this query output (there are 2 while statement and long query) as .csv format ? Now it's not save the result  as .csv format.

**Single Query, Like**

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from user_property upr,  offers ofr where ofr.property_id 
= upr.property_id  and ofr.agent_id IN (select id from users where company_name !='') order 
by accept_ind asc");
```

**Sql Query:**

```
<?php
// Database Connection
$host="host";
$uname="username";
$pass="password";
$database = "database"; 
$connection=mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pass); 
echo mysql_error();

//or die("Database Connection Failed");
$selectdb=mysql_select_db($database) or die("Database could not be selected");  
$result=mysql_select_db($database)
or die("database cannot be selected <br>");

$output = "`";

$q =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE company_name != '' ");
while($r= mysql_fetch_array($q)){

    $user_id = $r['id'];    
    $pc1 = $r['pc1'];
    $pc2 = $r['pc2'];
    $pc3 = $r['pc3'];
    $pc4 = $r['pc4'];                      
    $emailAgent = $r['user_email'];       

$sql =  mysql_query("
 SELECT * 
   FROM user_property upr 
  WHERE (postcode = '$pc1' OR
         postcode = '$pc2' OR
         postcode = '$pc3' OR
         postcode = '$pc4') AND
         datediff(CURDATE(), upr.creation_date) <= 7 AND
         NOT EXISTS(SELECT ofr.property_id 
                      FROM offers ofr 
                     WHERE ofr.property_id = upr.property_id AND
                           ofr.agent_id IN(SELECT id 
                                             FROM users 
                                            WHERE company_name !=''
                                          )
                   )
ORDER BY property_id DESC");

while($rrr =  mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 

    $columns_total  = mysql_num_fields($sql);

    // Get The Field Name   
    for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
        $heading    =   mysql_field_name($sql, $i);
        $output     .= '"'.$heading.'",';
    }
    $output .="\n";

    // Get Records from the table   
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $columns_total; $i++) {
        $output .='"'.$row["$i"].'",';
        }
        $output .="\n";
    }

    // Download the file    
    $filename =  "myFile.csv";
    header('Content-type: application/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);

    echo $output;
    exit;


    }// second while    
}/// first while...
?>
```

Comment: PHP had built in functions for creating CSV files. You should be using them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run 2 sql query with 1 query for save query result as .csv format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22179055/run-2-sql-query-with-1-query-for-save-query-result-as-csv-format)

Comment: @JohnConde with this code I can create CSV file with one query but can't create CSV file with `2 query with while statement (Sql Query)`.

Comment: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/